# How can I pass a reference to the current activity

Tags: java, android

I am trying to pass a reference of the current activity to an object but can't seem to find a method that will do this easily. Previously I was able to do this simple passing with the "this" reference of the current context. I then changed my activity from implementing OnClickListener to creating an OnClickListener object so that I could pass it as a parameter. This is when I ran into trouble as I was trying to create the object after I clicked on a button, this means I can no longer pass the activity with "this" because "this" is now a reference of the OnClickListener.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private Object mObject;

    private OnClickListener mListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Object mObject = new Object(this);
        }
    }
}

public class Object {
    private Activity mActivity;
    public Object(Activity a) {
        mActivity = a;
        mActivity.setContentView(R.layout.layout);
    }
}
```

Seems like an easy fix but I can't find the answer...

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: you put the letter m infront of a variable, to show it is a member variable i.e. is belongs to the class. You should not start your classes with this naming convention.   http://source.android.com/source/code-style.html

Comment: I do have the proper naming convention within my actual code, I simply over looked it for this particular example. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are right, `this` now references the `OnClickListener`, as it references the current class, and you are working inside an anonymous class. You can reference the outer activity by passing `mActivity.this`:

```
Object mObject = new Object(mActivity.this);
```

Btw: I think I'd rename the `mActivity` class, as normal class naming convention is for it to start with an uppercase letter.

Comment: Thank you very much, still learning Java and did not know I would be able to reference the Activity so simply. Also I do have the proper naming convention in my actual code, I simply was trying to get some example code out to better clarify.

Comment: I'm not much of a Java programmer myself, so I wondered about the same thing a little while ago. Glad to be of help. :)

Answer (score 3):

Add `mActivity.` to `this`

```
Object mObject = new Object(mActivity.this);
```

In  your context, `this` refers to a listener instance, but you need the outer class's instance there, so you need to add class name to `this`